# Static code analysis methodology

Tags: code-analysis, static-analysis

What methodology would you use with a static code analysis tool?

When and where would you run the analysis? How frequent?

How would you integrate it to a continues build environment, on daily builds? only nightly?

Comment: A static analysis tool to do what?  Detect the use of the word "foo"?  Isn't the goal kind of important?

Comment: No, detection of the word "foo" isn't needed :) What is needed (or at least my department thinks so) is a tool that runs on the source code and analyzes it to find bugs that can be found before runtime, like null pointer de-reference, double deletes in c++, etc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am using then on a new code base I set them up exactly how I want up front.  If I am using them on an existing code base I enable messages in stages, so that a particular category of issue is reported on.  Once that particular type of message is cleaned up I add the next category.

I treat static analysis tools as if they were part of the compiler.  Each developer runs them each time they do a build.  If possible I would also treat them as I do compiler warnings - as errors.  That way code with warnings does not make it onto the build server at all.  This has issues if you cannot turn warnings off in specific cases... and warnings should only be turned off by agreement.

Comment: In my case they decided to leave all issues found on tested code in place so that code will not need to be tested again (it released already) and fix the issues on the next code change in the area of an issue. But I like your approach, I think I would suggest that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that in general, static analysis should be used early in the development process, preferably (or ideally) before unit test and code check-in. Reports from static analysis can also be used during the code review process. This enables development of robust code by the software developer and in some cases writing code that can be analyzed more accurately by static analysis tools.

The challenge with early use is that software developers must be adequately trained to use static analysis tools and are able to effectively triage results obtained. That way, they can take concrete steps to improve the quality of the software. Otherwise, use of the tool diminishes or flagged issues are ignored and use of static analysis diminishes over time.

In practice most development organizations use static analysis late in the development process. In these phases, the static analysis tools are used by quality or test engineers. In many cases it is coupled with build systems to produce quality metrics and provide guidance about the safety and reliability of the software. However, if identified issues accumulate and span multiple code components, the probability that all issues will be fixed will decrease. Therefore, late use of static analysis in general may require more time and resource to address identified issues.

Comment: Thanks, I strongly agree and have witnessed the exact phenomena you described when using the static analysis in a late stage.

Answer (score 0):

It is also could be a good Idea to establish code review task (peer code review by another developer) together with using static-analysis tool so before checking the source code in the server. so it will help to increase the quality of code and preventing of useless lines of code that be useless legacy code one day.